# Kinect skeleton resizing / image reszing ?

Tags: c#, image, compare, kinect

I previously posted concerning c# kinect image comparison , I've overcome a number of the problems by taking screenshots of the skeleton stream on a black background in order to get over the problems inherent with comparing photos , Now my problem is that I need the images of the user to be compared to the presaved movements , however I'm having trouble when the users are not the same height as me , is there a way of overcoming this ? my only ideas involve either resizing the image or comparing the positions of certain colored pixels

Comment: What is the objective of your compare?  Your description almost makes it sound like you are trying to detect postures and/or gestures.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to compare the images. If you want to compare them pixel by pixel, You don't really need to resize, you just need a ratio to be used in the for-loop. For example if the size of image1 is WIDTH1*HEIGHT1 and the size of image2 is WIDTH2*HEIGHT2, you can use a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < HEIGHT1; j++)
    {
        pixel1 = image1[i][j];
        pixel2 = image2[i * WIDTH2/WIDTH1][j * HEIGHT2/HEIGHT1];
        // compare
    }
}
```

A more elegant method would be to compare pixel1 with a combination of multiple pixels from image2. For example if image1 is 300*300 and image2 is 600*600, then you can compare each pixel of image1 with the average RGB of 4 pixels in image2 (since for every pixel in image1, there exists four pixels in image2). In case the sizes are not divisible to each other, you may use weighted average. For example if image1 is 300*300 and image2 is 400*400, then you can compare pixel1 of image1 with a weighted average of 4 pixels in image2:

```
pixel1 = image1[i][j];
pixel2 = 0.75 * image2[i * WIDTH2/WIDTH1][j * HEIGHT2/HEIGHT1] + 
    0.25 * AVERAGE(image2[i * WIDTH2/WIDTH1 + 1][j * HEIGHT2/HEIGHT1] +
    image2[i * WIDTH2/WIDTH1][j * HEIGHT2/HEIGHT1 + 1] + 
    image2[i * WIDTH2/WIDTH1 + 1][j * HEIGHT2/HEIGHT1 + 1]);
```

Basically it means: pixel2 is 75% one pixel and 25% its neighbour pixels. With doing this you are actually doing a simple resizing algorithm (combining 4 different pixels into 1).